# WrappedArray to Array in HiveQL

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I'm using `collect_list` to group some column like:

```
val res = hiveContext.sql("SELECT date, time, collect_list(id) AS id_list FROM table1 GROUP BY date, time")
```

The `id_list` returns as a `WrappedArray`:

```
WrappedArray(1,2,1,2)
WrappedArray(4,3,4)
WrappedArray(6,7,6,7,6)
```

However I'm passing the `id_list` into `myFunc` that takes an `Array[Double]` as input:

```
def myFunc(xs: Array[Double]) {...}
```

My question is how can I call `myFunc` correctly to parse the `id_list`. I'm having something like:

```
res.collect.foreach(x => myFunc(x(2)))
```

but it's giving me an `type mismatch; found : Any required: Array[Double]` error.

What is the correct way to implicitly convert the `WrappedArray` into an `Array` or how can I call `myFunc` in an optimized way?

Thanks!

Comment: `scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray` has a def `array: Array[T]`, so invoke like this `res.collect.foreach(x => myFunc(x(2).array))` may solve you problem.

Comment: @AllenChou guess the main question here is how to let `x(2)` in type `Any` be recognized as an Array first instead of converting it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main question here is rather to explicitly convert `Any` to `WrappedArray[Double]` that you may do as:

```
x(2).asInstanceOf[mutable.WrappedArray[Double]].toArray
```

in your case. Or you may use pattern matching for type conversion that you may refer [How to use a Scala match expression instead of `isInstanceOf` (to match types)](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-match-case-expression-isinstanceof-types-scala) for details.

Comment: Thank you. I did try your solution and it worked. Initially it worked without the `mutable` too. Solved my issue.